# Discover location of database

Tags: database, web, ip, wireshark

I am trying to find the location of the database where a particular website is saving to.
The website is saving to some local database in our system, but I am unable to discover where.

I have tried using WireShark to find the IP of the machine where the website sends data to (i.e. the machine which has the database) but currently the only packets showing up are those from the website to my machine and vice versa.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start by tracking through the code & website config.  If you have sufficient access to run Wireshartk on the host can you not search for config files, find the serverside code, etc?

If you can't see packets on the network interface and you know you've found all network interfaces then it would appear possible the DB has to be on the same machine.  Check for recently changed files with you favourite tool (Windows explorer/search, find on Unix, etc).

Is it caching so you haven't yet caused it to read/write to a remote DB while watching?  Try watching Wireshark at boot up.

Depending on the nature of the data it could be an in memory DB or something that reads from a disk file into memory at boot up.

Comment: I have no access to code, only the website itself.I am not running Wireshark on the host machine. I am new to Wireshark, and that is why I was asking, because I'm not even sure if I can detect these packets, but I was hoping that there is a way to use Wireshark to detect all outgoing packets from a website, including those going to another machine on our network.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a Wireshark guru.  From my rather naive use of it I would assume that if you capture all packets for a period you should find any comms to a DB server.  Maybe try a new question with a Wireshark-oriented title